# H0;b1=0, b2=1 testing null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

> y = b1 + b2*x + error

test the null hypothesis H0; b1=0, b2=1

using R, I solved this problem like this.

```
P <-  read.csv("PS3-PPP.csv", header=T, na.string=".")
m1 <- lm((log(PPP)-log(EX)) ~ 0, data = P)
m2 <- lm((log(PPP)-log(EX))~log(EX), data = P)
anova(m1, m2)
```

These R codes are correct to test the null hypothesis? I don't know how to test the null hypothesis when the H0;b1=0, b2=1.

Please let me know if my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the approach and code that you have stated is correct, and the F-test in the output will test the null hypothesis that b1=0 and b2=1 vs the alternative that b1 and b2 are unspecified.
You are testing whether the relationship between log(PPP) and log(EX) is an identity line though zero.
The F-statistic will be on 2 and $n-2$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the number of parameters.

Just avoid any confusion, b1 and b2 represent here the population parameters rather than the least squares estimators.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!